# Nested Object mutates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am in almost desperate need of help. I am a mechanical engineer and I'm doing a type of calculator for my line of work. I have had an issue I've spent weeks on. I can't seem to solve it.

To not bore you with long code I will try to generalise it as much as possible.

- I will first present an example code.
- Then I will explain the expected behaviour and what is actually happening for me.
- Finally I will explain what I have tried so far to solve this issue.
- I will add more content at the bottom based on comments to help clarify my question.

**CODE EXAMPLE**

**THE PARENT OBJECT**

```
import {childObject} from "./childObject"

// in my code "childObject" are actually different from each other
const object1 = Object.assign({}, childObject);
const object2 = Object.assign({}, childObject);
const object3 = Object.assign({}, childObject);
const object4 = Object.assign({}, childObject);
const object5 = Object.assign({}, childObject);
const object6 = Object.assign({}, childObject);

const exampleObject = {
 name: "foo",
 otherInfo: "bar",
 nestedObject:{
  standardType: [object1, object2, object3],
  specialType: [object4, object5, object6]
 },
 sumfunc(){}
}
```

**THE CHILD OBJECT**

```
export const childObject = {
 name: "I'm losing my mind",
 value: "" //<-- this will change
 otherInfo: "please help me",
 sumfunc(){}
}
```

**EXPLAINING**

What I am doing is the following:

1. Searchbar with all types of parentObjects.
2. Allowing user to select one or multiple of same or different parentObjects.
3. Storing the copied selection in a redux store.
4. Displaying the selection, each parentObject as a form. [see picture]
5. When typing in form the value of the nested object will change

[image: example of forms]

Now... The issue is when I open the searchbar and select the same parentObject, thus copying it, all its values are mutated. As seen in picture above.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- I have tried to use lodash clone and deepClone on the selected parentObject.
- I have tried to use loads clone and deepClone on the selected childObjects.
- I have tried, since the object have the same structure, to go through all key value pairs and shallow copy them.
- I have tried to not send the parentObject via the searchbar component to the reducer, instead I just send a string and the reducer itself will add the parentObject to the store.

All methods that I've tried have not stopped the mutation. The deepClone method stopped the mutations, but in return the functions in the objects stopped working (maybe I need to bind it somehow?)

**MORE CONTENT**

**The code that updates the value of the nestedObject**

```
const inputsHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const formCopy = Object.assign({}, formEQ);
    const inputFieldName = e.target.name;

    // if anything other than a empty, number or decimal inputted, then return
    const isNum = e.target.value.match(/^(?:\d{1,8}(?:\.\d{0,8})?)?$/);
    if (!isNum) return;
    // Update priority list to calculate the last updated input
    formCopy.priorityList = formCopy.priorityList.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a === inputFieldName) return 1;
      if (b === inputFieldName) return -1;
      else return 0;
    });
    // Update selected input field
    formCopy.inputs[calcmode] = formCopy.inputs[calcmode].map((input) => {
      if (input.name === inputFieldName) {
        input.value = e.target.value;
      }
      return input;
    });

    // If more than two inputs empty do not calculate
    const emptyInputs = formCopy.inputs[calcmode].reduce(
      (acc, nV) => (nV.value === "" ? (acc += 1) : acc),
      0
    );

    // Calculate the last edited input field
    formCopy.inputs[calcmode] = formCopy.inputs[calcmode].map((input) => {
      if (input.name === formCopy.priorityList[0] && emptyInputs <= 1) {
        const calculatedValue = formCopy.calculate(
          formCopy.priorityList[0],
          calcmode
        );
        input.value = Number(calculatedValue).toFixed(2);
      }
      return input;
    });

    // Final set hook, now with calculated value
    setformEQ({ ...formCopy });
  };
```

Please good people of StackOverFlow... Help me!

Comment: Can you share how you're updating the object ?

Comment: In `nestedObject`, i see `nestedObject:{ standardType: [object1, object2, object3], specialType: [object1, object4, object5] }`.  do you realize that `object1` is listed in both `standardType` and `specialType` ?   Also, are you looping over these properties and printing out the indexes?  Are you applying a `key` to each element as you print it out?  what does that part of you code look like. And like programoholic asked, how are you updating the object?

Comment: @programoholic I have added it at the bottom.

Comment: @JonathonHibbard
Thank you for pointing out the mistake! I have not applied any key to the nestedObject, should I do that? I have only applied keys to what react has told me to in the console.

Comment: Well your code is very complex.. can you produce a codesandbox or stackblitz . I will fix this

Comment: @programoholic
Yes, will do so tomorrow, night time here now, will have to go to work early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has few problems :

1. you are filtering based on `name` property of child object and all of them has the same name. Always provide unique `id` to the objects so that they can be differentiated in easy manner.
2. Your filter logic is so wrong :

   ```
    formCopy.inputs[calcmode] = formCopy.inputs[calcmode].map((input) => {
         if (input.name === inputFieldName) {
           input.value = e.target.value; // < -- Culprit
         }
         return input;
       });
   ```

Never mutate inline, always create a new copy.

This is how your code `change` function should be (I have removed dynamic key selection for clarity) :

```
  const change = (e, id) => {
    const inputFieldName = e.target.name;

    // local copy of array
    const nestedArr = [...qform.nestedObject.standardType];

    // finding item to be updated
    const index = nestedArr.findIndex((i) => i.id === id);

    console.log({ index, inputFieldName, e, id });

    if (index !== -1) {
      const item = nestedArr[index];
      item.value = e.target.value;
      nestedArr[index] = item;

      // deep copy till k depth where k is the key to be updated
      const newObject = {
        ...qform,
        nestedObject: {
          ...qform.nestedObject,
          standardType: [...nestedArr],
        },
      };

      setQform(newObject);
    }}
```

Check this Example : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a5jhqz?file=src/App.js)

Comment: I had some time to change my code today @programoholic. It is not duplicating, I have yet to implement your suggested solution. I will keep my question open, until I have implemented your solution. But I think that you have helped me in solving my issue :)!